# the char presenting bitset c#

Tags: c#, bit, bitset

I have a system which should return if first entity is ok or the second one or both of them.
I decided to return char ,representing a bitmap : i.e. 
00 - no one,01 - the first, 10 the second,11 - both.
When I read the values, if the result sits in `char res`  I check `res %2 == 1` and `res / 2 == 1`
My team lead said that it is not readable
What do you propose to do it better?

Comment: Use an `enum` with the `Flags` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up an enum like this:

```
[Flags]
enum myBitSet  : ushort
{ 
    none = 0,
    firstThing = 1,
    secondThing = 2,
    bothThings = 3   // or better firstThing | secondThing
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
if ((test & myBitSet.firstThing) == myBitSet.firstThing) 
{
    // firstThing was set
}
```

Which is easier to read because you don't have to remember which bit is which.

And:

```
if ((test & myBitSet.bothThings) > 0) 
{
    // either firstThing, secondThing or both were set.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what your system is. A class, a method, a framework?

A method can return several results through `out` parameters

```
public void CheckEntities(Entity a, Entity b, out bool isAOK, out bool isBOK)
{
    isAOK = Test(a);
    isBOK = Test(b);
}
```

You can also create a dedicated type

```
public class EntitiesStatus
{
    public EntitiesStatus(bool isAOK, bool isBOK)
    {
        IsEntity1OK = isAOK;
        IsEntity2OK = isBOK;
    }

    IsEntity1OK { get; private set; }
    IsEntity2OK { get; private set; }
}
```

You can use an enum

```
[Flags]
public enum EntityStatus
{
    NoneIsOK = 0,
    FirstIsOK = 1,   // = 2^0
    SecondIsOK = 2,  // = 2^1
    BothAreOK = FirstIsOK | SecondIsOK;
}
```

When using the `FlagsAttribute`, make sure that the enum constants the can be combined are all powers of two. This ensures that any combination of them yields distinct values.

You have a lot of options, but don't use some "magic" bit manipulations that make look your code like early days c code and requires extra knowledge from those using your `char` result. And by the way, why `char`? Even just using an `int` and constants would be better (while not optimal). `const int FirstIsOK = 1, SecondIsOK = 2; int result FirstIsOK + SecondIsOK;`. This requires no bit manipulations.